# Cannot get my current health in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been having  problem recently with my `CharacterStats` class. I set the up a two floats. `CurrentHealth` and `MaxHealth`. On `Awake()`, I wanted the `CurrentHealth` to equal the `MaxHealth`, and decrease once damage is taken, but it has just been equaling zero.

It worked when I started, but it stopped working a couple days later after adding more scenes and more game objects. Is there something that I am missing, or could this be a bug in Unity?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterStats : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int MaxHealth = 100;
    public int CurrentHealth { get; private set; }
    public Stat damage;
    // public Stat armor;For later game updates
    void Awake()
    {
        CurrentHealth = MaxHealth;

    }
    void Update()
    {
        /* if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
         {
             TakeDamage(10);
         }*/
    }
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        //damage -= armor.GetValue();
        damage = Mathf.Clamp(damage, 0, int.MaxValue);
        CurrentHealth -= damage;
        Debug.Log(transform.name + "takes" + damage + "damage.");

        if (CurrentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }
    public virtual void Die()
    {


        //Overrride
        Debug.Log(transform.name + "You died.....sad");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is Awake() being called?

Comment: @MichaelRoy `Awake` is called by Unity.

Comment: What is `Stat`?

Comment: @Lece Ah, OK.  Never really messed around with Unity.

Comment: How are calling `TakeDamage`? If you're calling it as shown in the commented `Update` code, replace `Input.GetKey` with `Input.GetKeyDown`. `GetKey` will repeat so `health` will hit zero in 10  frames or 0.33 seconds at 30FPS.

Comment: Did you incidentally change `MaxHealth` in the inspector (that would override the = 100)? By 'right away' you mean it's set to 0 in Awake? Or are you potentially calling `TakeDamage` unintentionally? Try adding some `Debug.Log`-statements to figure out when and with which values `TakeDamage` is called.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code.  I am almost 100% sure you are doing something somewhere else in your game or editor.  Check the object that the script is attached to.  As the MaxHealth is public, you may have set it to 0 in the editor field.

Comment: @RonBeyer Stat is a serialized class to get the values for damage and armor.

Comment: Im sorry @GunnarB. I wasn't being very specific. My CurrentHealth, is the one that is set to zero. At first, it said, -1300, then -70 once i made the character static and non static out of desperation. It doesnt make since to me, because it was working originally. I thought that it could be my health bar, but that is working fine too. It is set to zero just like the CurrentHealth, but maybe I am over looking something.

Comment: void Update () {
        if (Player3d)
        {
            HpScale.x = (float)Player3d.CurrentHealth / Player3d.MaxHealth;
        }
        else if (player3d)
        {

            HpScale.x = (float)player3d.CurrentHealth / player3d.MaxHealth;
        }
        else if (Rikio2d)
        {
            HpScale.x = (float)Rikio2d.CurrentHealth / Rikio2d.MaxHealth;
        }
        else if (Naachan2d)
        {
            HpScale.x = (float) Naachan2d.CurrentHealth / Naachan2d.MaxHealth;
        }
        this.transform.localScale = HpScale;
        
 }
}

Comment: Did you add the clamp after getting those negative values? Anyways, to me, getting those values pretty much proves that you are calling `TakeDamage` a lot of times. Add a `Debug.Log("Taking damage");` to the function and see if that shows up in the console while just idling in play mode.

Comment: @GunnarB. I just did that, and nothing pops up until an enemy hits me. I just learned that if I put two characters on the screen, then it fixes itself.